# What is the equivalent of layer-list in jetpack compose with 2 gradients?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

currently I have a layer list drawable in xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="0.3"
                    android:centerY="0.4"
                    android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                    android:gradientRadius="700"
                    android:startColor="#2649C447"
                    android:type="radial" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="0.8"
                    android:centerY="0.6"
                    android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                    android:gradientRadius="700"
                    android:startColor="#267E2BD6"
                    android:type="radial" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

I want to use compose to make exact same UI using compose,
Can some one tell me how to make this in compose?

Comment: Would you mind sharing an image of how this gradient looks like in xml?